# Fixed div when scrolling an html document

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im looking for a jquery plugin that lets me do this effect:
[static scrolldown](http://www.bnet.com/blog/drug-business/it-8217s-a-trap-congress-wants-to-see-j-j-ceo-squirm-over-tylenol-recalls/4997)

Scroll down... you will notice that the block at the left always stays fixed -attached to the top. Any ideas? I don't know where to start searching.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this blog post on the technique:

http://www.massless.org/?archive=2008/12/pegs-experiment-in-page-layout-and

includes a demo, should be enough to get you started

Comment: hi again... somehow this does not work when google adsense is present :s