# "How to Ask" box when typing a question in SO. How do get that scrolling effect? Pure CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm wondering how to make the effect of the tan rectangle as you scroll it follows (some kind of absolute positioning?), check it out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

When scrolling downwards it sticks on the screen. Me like and me want :D

I'd prefer JS targeting an elementID over CSS. If anyone can provide a tutorial or even the coding that would be awesome. The cleaner and less strict, the better. Cheers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed div when scrolling an html document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121226/fixed-div-when-scrolling-an-html-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's CSS:

```
<div id="scroller" style="width: 270px; position: fixed; ">
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#fixed-positioning for further information.

"position: fixed" is probably what you're after. In your own code you can set the style of an element with JS code directly, or you can set an element class and put position: fixed it in your CSS.

In the future you can look up such things with tools such as Firebug (for Firefox) or inspect tool for Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, I have csscan on Google Chrome, it isn't that good to be honest. Inspect Tool? Mind if I can have the link?

Comment: It's integrated in Chrome, you don't need to install anything. Right-click anywhere you like on the page and click "Inspect element".

Comment: By the way, Internet Explorer has developer tools built in too, just press F12.

Comment: Thanks. However SO has made it better when you scroll back up, its kind of pushed back to the original position by the header (sorry I can't describe it any better). Any clue on that?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jQuery plugin](http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/) out, it does exactly that along with a nice animation.

Comment: Oops this isn't a jQuery question. Ignore my answer I'll leave it as reference in case someone IS using jQuery. Can't find any vanilla solutions, but it wouldn't be very hard to implement.

Comment: No problems, I plan on using jQuery sooner or later. The demo looks a little distracting when scrolling, but I guess the settings can be changed.