# making a div in fixed mode in top browser when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div element which isn't at the top, but rather in the middle of the page.
I would like it to get fixed to the top of the browser when I scroll down to it.
How can I achieve that? especially the event for it.
Thanks.

Comment: @UmairP, I may use jQuery, is there scrollDown event?

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121226/fixed-div-when-scrolling-an-html-document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      // write code to move the div.
     var top = $("#mydiv").offset().top;
     var left = $("#mydiv").offset().left;
    });
});
```

Comment: how can I get a top position of a certain div and the top position of the window so I will know when I reach the div when scrolling down?

Comment: code edited... dont bother about the window position , it rame always the same

Comment: Don't I need to check when it's equal to the window?

Comment: yes, Just look for div off its less or greater  than a value then do ur work

Comment: how can I distinguish between scrollup and down?

Comment: Keep a variable, say, last_scroll_position, and when you have a scroll, if last_scroll_position - current_position > 0, the user scrolled up, and down if it's less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a CSS class for that div and in that class you should use css property like

```
position:fixed
top:0;
left:0
```

Comment: How can I catch the event for it ? I don't want it to be fixed from the beginning, I want it only to get fixed when I scroll down to the div element

Comment: Well, then you have to change certain css properties when you scroll down your page. In javascript you can easily detect how much pixel you have scrolled on your page, and then fires a function to change the div position to fixed and top let's say 100. Initially your css class should not include position fixed, use position absolute, and when u fired the function change the css properties to fixed for that div. So.. before scroll your class should be position absolute,top and left 0, after scroll css should be position fixed, top 100 and left 0.

Answer (score 0):

use **position: fixed** , it's a CSS work

Answer (score 0):

You can add i like this

```
 .notification-box {
      position: fixed;
       top:20px;
       right:20px;
       width:300px;
           border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
           z-index:99;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/C3AmC/

Give position after which you want to scroll.

**Note** Although don't know if it is the best approach

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if(scrollTop>150){
        $('.middle').css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0'});
    }
});​
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/7ymuD/